# Meteor MongoDB Document Update

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm getting an an error `MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage.`

```
const modifier = { $set: {}, $inc: { 'hearts.counter': 1 } };
modifier.$set[`hearts.records${i}.expDate`] = expDate;
Meteor.users.update(lookUpUser._id, { modifier });
```

So far I tried:

```
Meteor.users.update(lookUpUser._id, modifier);
```

and

```
const modifier = { $set: {}, $inc: {} };
modifier.$inc['hearts.counter'] = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me please?

EDIT:
My users collection looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "xxxxx",
  "username": "xxxx",
  "hearts": {
    "counter": 0,
    "records": [{
      "owner": "xxxxx",
      "expDate": Date
    }, {
      "owner": "xxxxx",
      "expDate": Date
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm looping through document's array `hearts.records` and if `hearts.records[index].expDate` is 30 days over `new Date()` then update `$inc hearts.counter` by 1 and `$set hearts.records[index].expDate` to new `expDate`.. I hope that was clear

Comment: Try putting a dot in the other property `hearts.records.${i}.expDate`

Comment: I tried it just now. Still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way you are doing it, `$set` is an array, not an object. And as @chridam mentioned, you probably need to add a dot. Try this:

```
const modifier = { $set: {}, $inc: { 'hearts.counter': 1 } };
modifier.$set = { [`hearts.records.${i}.expDate`]: expDate }
Meteor.users.update(lookUpUser._id, modifier);
```

or directly:

```
const modifier = {
  $set: {
    [`hearts.records.${i}.expDate`]: expDate,
  },
  $inc: {
    'hearts.counter': 1,
  },
};
Meteor.users.update(lookUpUser._id, modifier);
```